# Read the file with python cgi

Tags: python, cgi, cgi-bin

I have data with a .txt extension . I want to read the file, but the result of his error `result < cStringIO.StringO object at 0x7f5078d18068 >` What 's wrong ?

My file

```
Abedus
Accer
Chrome
```

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/my.py" method="post">
            <p>File: <input type="file" name="filename"></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

CGI Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()


form = cgi.FieldStorage()
data = form['filename'].file    

print "Content-Type: text/plain"
print ""
print "result %s" % data,
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not upload a file and read cgi python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483132/can-not-upload-a-file-and-read-cgi-python)

Comment: yes I create Again the question because it can not solve my problem Question